# SQL query to find the repetitions of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a sample data

```
id    date        user_id    customer_id     status
 1   2022-06-23      1            12         no response
 2   2022-06-23      1            12         no response
 3   2022-06-24      1            12         no response
 4   2022-06-23      2            15         no response
 4   2022-06-23      2            15         successful
 5   2022-06-23      3            16         call later
```

I need to fetch those kind of records where a user_id called the same customer_id on the same day got only no response status more than once but not any other statuses.

The result for the above example would be

```
id
1
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT user_id, customer_id, date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id, customer_id, date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(status <> 'no response') = 0
```

If you want the respective rows of the table use the above query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (user_id, customer_id, date) IN (
  SELECT user_id, customer_id, date
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY user_id, customer_id, date
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(status <> 'no response') = 0
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57ac4c64a00d8bca8d5d64c09a8fa257).